# VScode unable to write into user settings

Tags: error, visual-studio-code

I edited the VScode settings in settings.json file

/* "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 13
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Monaco"
*/

I had to comment them out because VScode started to give error message every time I modified other settings too.

The error message: Unable to write into user settings

Comment: Some context would make it easier to find answers here. How did you edit that file, where is it stored, what are its permissions?

Comment: I edited it in VScode as instructed. it's a VScode standard. Permissions are presumed to be ok since the file was working before editing.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. There are missing commas (,) in the settings code. The settings code works without the commas, it produces the desired results, but creates error messages later in the app.